# Is possible change css from a xpath node?

Tags: javascript, xpath

For example in javascript using getelementbyid:

```
document.getElementById("theID").style.width="100%";
```

can i change the css from the node retrieved by xpath like with getelementbyid?

Comment: With XPath you can query XML, not change it.

Comment: There is no "XPath" here. Please consider posting a *real* example/intended usage. Also, it doesn't matter *how* an Element is found in the DOM (gEBI, CSS selectors, XPath): DOM Elements can be mutated, as what is done in the posted code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, i did it like this:

```
var xpath = 'your xpath';

var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

matchingElement.style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

`xpath= $x('//body'); // this will return an array usually containing 1 element`

`xpath[0].classList.value=""; // edit class name`

`xpath[0].style.display="none"; // edit style attributes`

useful links I found:
https://devhints.io/xpath#class-check

[How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)